# Angular input type date: how to get the current date preset?

Tags: angular

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="regDate">Registration date:</label>
  <input id="regDate" name="regDate" class="form-control" required type="date" #nameField="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="weightData.regDate">
  {{ weightData.regDate | date: 'dd/MM/yyy' }}
</div>
```

I'm using Angular, but for this first test I just want to use regular input fields. I've set weightData.regDate to today's date. The interploation with the pipe is working fine. But in the input field I keep getting "dd-----yyyy". How can I set the correct date with binding immediately?

[image]

I've put up an example on StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1gqxq1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the date pipe to format the date as follows,

```
 <input  type="date" id="regDate" name="regDate" class="form-control" required type="date" #nameField="ngModel"  [ngModel]="regDate | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'"  >
```

[STACKBLITZ DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pqx9qu?file=src/app/app.component.html)